# Possible to isElementPresent(:id, "id") in watir webdriver

Tags: watir-webdriver

Using Watir Webdriver, I wanted to have a helper that would check for any element with given id. I may not know what type it is ( button or link or text). Can I just do

`browser.Element(:id, id).exists`

All of the examples i've found on google check against a specific element type, as in

`browser.button(:id," ").exits`

If there is a way, please share the syntax.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

In Watir-Webdriver, I would use something like this:

```
browser.element(class: 'post-tag').exists?
```

which would find the watir-webdriver tag on this page and report that it exists. Note that I used the 1.9 syntax instead of the alternative syntaxes of:

```
browser.element(:class => 'post-tag').exists?
```

or

```
browser.element(:class, 'post-tag').exists?
```

Answer (score 0):

As Dave points out, there is `#element` method. (You were wrong just in capitalization, it is not `#Element`.)

Since you are asking about accessing it using `id` attribute, try this:

```
browser.element(:id => id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never gotten .exists? to work right on it's own.

What I've had to use in these cases has been to explicitly validate the "exist?"... like:

```
cf_checbox = @browser.text_field(:id=>'continue-ring', :value=>true).exists?

assert( cf_description == true)
```

without that explicit assertion, I would always get a "true" even when the value didn't exist.